How should I add EMT conduit before drywall?
I want to have my electrical upgraded to 200A which involves adding multiple new conduit runs.  My garage is currently unfinished and eventually walls and ceiling will be covered in Type X drywall.  I want the electric upgrade to happen asap, and the drywall may not happen until late this year.
What guidance do you have that would easily allow for running conduit first and then drywall after the fact?    My idea is to use a conduit hanger to offset the conduit and 1/2 plywood for the j-box which would later be removed and then slip drywall between joists and conduit.


Drill holes in the studs and use ENT or FMC behind the drywall.

Are you adding multiple conduit runs because your upgrade will give you additional headroom, i.e. are there going to be new circuits?  Why do you need conduit for that?

@huesmann replacing romex, fmc, cloth wrapped, and many 1/2 emt with 3 EMT either 3/4 or 1"

You realize you're only allowed 4 circuits per conduit, right?  And you need to follow conduit fill rules unless it's a very simple run.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica I did not know that.  3/4 EMT can take (16) 12AWG conductors, I thought that meant 8 circuits.

You're overlooking thermal adjustment factors, see 310.15(B)(3)(a). https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=60  With 16 conductors in a pipe, #12 "adjusts" to 15A and #10 "adjusts" to 20A.

TIL.  Thanks Harper.  I also found this for reference https://www.jlconline.com/how-to/electrical/q-a-3-4-inch-conduit-capacity_o

As @Ecnerwal says, put it behind the drywall.  Rough in everything just as you would if you were running NM cable, except that it will be conduit instead of NM cable.  Use EMT as much as possible, only using FMC where you need to take advantage of the flexibility of FMC, e.g. running perpendicular to joists.
There are some tips for running conduit in this post.

If you drill right through the outside wall and keep the holes in a straight line you can run EMT perpendicular to framing after the fact. But it's usually more of a PITA than it's worth, (now you have to patch holes in the wall) so FMC (for picky locations like Chicago, or "because rodent resistance" anywhere.) ENT if you just want conduit and don't have Chicago-esque rules and/or want to spend less money.
